# How can I make the turtle function calculate the total length value drawn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I need my turtle to draw any regular polygon the user wants where they click on the screen
and also printing out the total length of the polygons they draw.

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
tlength=0

def figure(num, length):       
    for i in range(num):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(360/num)
        global tlength
        tlength = tlength+length

        
def drawit(x, y):              
    shape = int(turtle.textinput("","What Shape?"))

    if shape!="0":
        length = int(turtle.textinput("","The length of side? "))
       
    
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    figure(shape, length)
    t.write("total drawn length=", tlength)

s = turtle.Screen()
s.onscreenclick(drawit)
```

This is what I have so far.. It works well except it wont print out the total length. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please fix your code formatting? It's hard to understand your code otherwise.

Comment: Why don't you use ```t.xcor()```?

Answer (score 0):

You have some code issues:

```
t.write("total drawn length=", tlength)
```

This won't work as `write()` doesn't take multiple arguments to display but rather just one.  Check the documentation.

```
shape = int(...)

if shape != "0":
```

You just forced `shape` to be an `int` but then test if it's not a string -- this will always be true.  Also, the `int()` call will fail if the user hits "Cancel" and `textinput()` returns `None`.

```
tlength=0
```

This only gets initialized once, so any subsequent polygons will add the perimeters of the previous polygons to their total length.

Here's rework of your program that fixes most of the above issues and basically works:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def figure(sides, length):
    perimeter = 0

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        perimeter += length

        turtle.left(360 / sides)

    return perimeter

def drawit(x, y):
    shape = screen.textinput("", "How many sides?")

    if not shape:
        return

    length = screen.textinput("", "The length of one side?")

    if not length:
        return

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    total_length = figure(int(shape), int(length))
    turtle.write("Total drawn length = " + str(total_length))

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(drawit)
screen.mainloop()
```